# How add orbit-db in bundle?

Tags: ipfs, orbitdb

## I want create orbitdb bundle

In README on github i see this example

```
npm install orbit-db ipfs

const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const OrbitDB = require('orbit-db')
```

i am using es6 `import`
In example for browser on [github](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/blob/master/examples/browser/browser-webpack-example/index.js)

```
// Import IPFS module
import IPFS from 'ipfs'

// Import OrbitDB module from 'orbit-db', eg. directory to its package.json
import OrbitDB from '../../..'
```

But it is not work

I build es5 modules

```
npm run build:es5
```

it is build not es5 modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build *this* example run the following commands

```
npm install
npm run build:examples
```

after that you can open `examples/browser/browser-webpack-example/index.html` in your browser.

Edit: We updated the [documentation](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db#examples) to run the examples